# Playframework migrating from 2.4 to 2.5 : java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempted to call materialize()

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka

While migrating from play framework 2.4 to play framework 2.5.3 I am facing this one particular error which I have no clue of,

(This is a multi module project)

```
[ERROR] [06/01/2016 15:12:26.294] [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl(application)] Uncaught fatal error from thread [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] shutting down ActorSystem [application]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lplay/libs/F$Predicate;
```

and

```
[DEBUG] [06/01/2016 15:12:26.412] [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [EventStream] shutting down: StandardOutLogger started
[error] - play.core.server.netty.PlayRequestHandler - Exception caught in channelRead future
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempted to call materialize() after the ActorMaterializer has been shut down.
```

I have tried to adding "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-persistence-experimental" % "2.3.4"

etc but have no happy news till now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely that you have a library (maybe third party) that has been compiled against Play 2.4. Could also be that you haven't run sbt clean. If it's a library that's been compiled against Play 2.4, see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SBTDebugging#Debugging-dependencies for how to diagnose - what you're looking for is something that depends on Play 2.4.x but where 2.4 has been excluded.